# How can I use loops to simplify this long if-else code?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm new to coding and we're learning about loops and conditions.

For exercise, I'm supposed to write a code which follows: "***Request 10 numbers from a user and count, how many are positive, negative, or zero. Also, count odd and even. Display the statistics.
There’s only one variable (not 10) needed for input by a user.***"

So far, I have this code, but it's too long (I intentionally stopped at the third number), and it doesn't respect the condition that there needs to be only one variable needed for input by the user. Can I do this using loops? Is it possible? We haven't learned about arrays yet.

```js
var posCount = 0; var negCount = 0; var zeroCount = 0; 
var evenCount = 0;var oddCount = 0;

let n1 = prompt('Enter number 1:');
let n2 = prompt('Enter number 2:');
let n3 = prompt('Enter number 3:');
if (n1 > 0) {
    posCount++;
} else if (n1 == 0) {
    zeroCount++;
} else {
    negCount++;
}
if (n1 % 2 == 0) {
    evenCount++;
}
else {
    oddCount++;
}

if (n2 > 0) {
    posCount++;
} else if (n2 == 0) {
    zeroCount++;
} else {
    negCount++;
}
if (n2 % 2 == 0) {
    evenCount++;
}
else {
    oddCount++;
}

if (n3 > 0) {
    posCount++;
} else if (n3 == 0) {
    zeroCount++;
} else {
    negCount++;
}
if (n3 % 2 == 0) {
    evenCount++;
}
else {
    oddCount++;
}

console.log('There are ' + negCount + ' negative numbers');
console.log('There are ' + posCount + ' positive numbers');
console.log('There are ' + zeroCount + ' 0s');
console.log('There are ' + oddCount + ' odd numbers');
console.log('There are ' + evenCount + ' even numbers');
```

Comment: Yes, you should use a loop for this. _“We haven't learned about arrays yet.”_ - doesn’t need arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you some hints instead of a direct solution so as not to spoil your exercise.

It's important to learn that you don't have to store all inputs at once, since you don't need them simultaneously.

Hover your mouse over this block if you want a more detailed hint.

> You can prompt for one, process it, and then prompt for the next one.

This way you can use a loop without bothering about arrays, and only one variable is needed for reading input.

Finally, some real code if you still have trouble understanding:

> ```
> var posCount = 0; var negCount = 0; var zeroCount = 0;
> var evenCount = 0;var oddCount = 0;
>
> for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
>   let n = prompt("Enter number " + i);
>   // Process n
> }
>
> console.log('There are ' + negCount + ' negative numbers');
> // More console.log output
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?. I added an array since it makes the code very simple. hope you can catch up.

```
    let n = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        n[i] = prompt('Enter number 1:');
        if (n[i] > 0) {
            posCount++;
        } else if (n[i] == 0) {
            zeroCount++;
        } else {
            negCount++;
        }
        if (n[i] % 2 == 0) {
            evenCount++;
        } else {
            oddCount++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No you don't need the array *at all*.